# How can I control the formatting of Data::Dumper's output?

Tags: perl, dump, data-dumper

I am using `Data::Dumper::Dumper()` method. The output is good, but can be made little compact and more good looking.

How I can control it? What are the better alternatives?

Comment: What exactly is it you don't like about Data::Dumper's output?

Comment: There are tons of options to Data::Dumper. See [the documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Data::Dumper#Configuration_Variables_or_Methods). You can fix indentation, padding, variable names, depth, key sorting, etc.

Comment: Echoing Manni: You should read the docs and point out what other improvements you need than those that can be achieved by tweaking parameters.

Comment: I hope you're not using this for production, because that would be the only reason I can see that you would want to make it prettier. It shows the data structure. It's not supposed to be pretty.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Take a look at [Data::Dump](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data::Dump) for something similar to Data::Dumper but arguably better at pretty printing.

**Edit (20120304)**: I had completely forgotten this question, but it was upvoted today and that jogged my memory. If I had to recommend anything today (3 years later) for pretty printing in Perl, I would *certainly* go with [Data::Printer](https://metacpan.org/module/Data::Printer). From Data::Printer's own Rationale:

> Data::Dumper is a fantastic tool, meant to stringify data structures in a way they are suitable for being `eval`'ed back in.
>
> The thing is, a lot of people keep using it (and similar ones, like Data::Dump) to print data structures and objects on screen for inspection and debugging, and while you **can** use those modules for that, it doesn't mean mean you **should**.
>
> This is where Data::Printer comes in. It is meant to do one thing and one thing only:
> *display Perl variables and objects on screen, properly formatted* (to be inspected by a human)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to serialize output for storage (rather than for display), take a look at  [Storable](http://perldoc.perl.org/Storable.html)'s `freeze()` and `thaw()`.  I cringe whenever I see Data::Dumper being used to save data structures in a DB or cache. :(

Answer (score 4):

I normally use Data::Dump::Streamer, but as the others said, only when the options to Data::Dumper aren't enough.

Answer (score 3):

One alternative<sup>*</sup> to [Data::Dumper](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Data::Dumper) would be [JSON](http://json.org/) and its Perl implementation [JSON](http://search.cpan.org/dist/JSON).

**<sup>*</sup>** Whether it is better is up to you to decide.

Comment: It's certainly better for cross-platform or cross-language communication, such as preparing a data structure to be received by javascript or a Flash application. There are JSON libraries for most modern languages, and many post-modern and decrepit ones too. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking for dump output: [`Smart::Comments`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Smart::Comments.).

You just `use` it.

```
use Smart::Commments;
```

And then you put any simple variable in a three-hash comment, like so:

```
my $v = black_box_process();
### $v
```

And it dumps it out in almost the prettiest print possible.

You can also manage more complex expressions like so:

```
### ( $a && ( $b ^ ( $c || $d ))) : ( $a && ( $b ^ ( $c || $d )))
```

But you have to watch it for "colon paths".

```
### $My::Package::variable
```

or

### %My::Package::

has *never* worked in my experience. If I want them to work then I need something like this:

```
my %stash = %My::Package::;
### %stash
```

It also does a number of other cute tricks, which you can see if you read the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use [Data::Dumper::Perltidy](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Data::Dumper::Perltidy) which is a (more or less) drop-in replacement for Data::Dumper::Dumper() but which uses Perltidy to format the output.

Answer (score 2):

[Data::Dumper::Concise](http://search.cpan.org/~frew/Data-Dumper-Concise-2.020/lib/Data/Dumper/Concise.pm) is another possibility.

```
use Data::Dumper::Concise;
warn Dumper($var);
```

is equivalent to:

```
use Data::Dumper;
{
  local $Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;
  local $Data::Dumper::Indent = 1;
  local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
  local $Data::Dumper::Deparse = 1;
  local $Data::Dumper::Quotekeys = 0;
  local $Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;
  warn Dumper($var);
}
```