# Is there a less verbose alternative to Perl's Data::Dumper?

Tags: perl, data-dumper

I'm trying to print some parse trees, and `Data::Dumper` is very verbose for that, for example printing:

```
{
  'A' => {
    'ID' => 'y'
  },
  'OP' => '=',
  'B' => {
    'NUM' => '5'
  }
},
```

rather than let's say:

```
{
  'A' => {'ID' => 'y'},
  'OP' => '=',
  'B' => {'NUM' => '5'}
},
```

and it's very hard to read since it take massive number of lines.

Is there any Perl library which does what `Data::Dumper` does except more tersely, or do I need to write my own?

Comment: Are none of the options for [`$Data::Dumper::Indent`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html#Configuration-Variables-or-Methods) useful to you?

Comment: Perhaps this question is useful

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595557/how-can-i-control-the-formatting-of-datadumpers-output

Comment: It's already with `$Data::Dumper::Indent=1; $Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;`

Comment: Oops, indeed. I guess I'll edit my answer to alternative modules then.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want [`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/module/Data::Dump#HISTORY) :

> **HISTORY**
>
> The `Data::Dump` module grew out of frustration with Sarathy's
>   in-most-cases-excellent `Data::Dumper`. Basic ideas and some code are
>   shared with Sarathy's module. The `Data::Dump` module provides a much
>   simpler interface than `Data::Dumper`.

[`Data::Printer`](https://metacpan.org/module/Data::Printer) is a more modern alternative with colored output.

Comment: I know I'll catch flak, but I prefer Data::Dump to Data::Dumper. I guess it's just whatcha know and are used to.  :-)

Answer (score 4):

You mean besides [Data::Dumper::Concise](http://p3rl.org/Data%3a%3aDumper%3a%3aConcise)? :)

Answer (score 0):

If using [`$Data::Dumper::Indent`](http://p3rl.org/Data%3a%3aDumper#Configuration-Variables-or-Methods) is not enough, you may like to try JSON or YAML module families, if you only need data to be human-readable (i.e. for debugging). Their format is close enough to Perl's own to read easily and they have many formatting options.